# Existe algo semelhante ao Optional Chaining (encadeamento opcional) do JavaScript no PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Sabemos que em JavaScript:

> O *optional chaining* (operador de encadeamento opcional) `?.` permite a leitura do valor de uma propriedade localizada internamente em uma cadeia de objetos conectados, sem que a validação de cada referência da cadeia seja expressivamente realizada. <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)</sup>

Ou seja, é uma maneira segura de acessar propriedades de objetos aninhados, mesmo se uma propriedade intermediária não existir.

```js
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
// output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.());
// output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.cat.name);
// output: Dinah

console.log(adventurer?.cat?.cat?.name);
// output: undefined
// nenhum erro será lançado
```

Um amigo meu de faculdade, achou maravilhoso esse recurso do JavaScript e ele queria saber se existe isso em PHP (eu não sabia responder). O objetivo era simplificar um trecho de código <s>infernal</s> dele, demonstrado abaixo:

```php
...

if ($session !== null) {
    $admin = $session->adminUser;
    ...
    if ($admin !== null) {
        $credential = $admin->getAuthCredentials();
        ...
        if ($credential !== null) {
            $data = $credential->email;
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

<sup><sup>Detalhe, essa escada causada pelos `if`s cresce ainda mais..., ele só mandou um trecho pra exemplificar.</sup></sup>

No JavaScript seria algo como:

```js
const credential = session?.adminUser?.getAuthCredentials?.()
const data = credential?.email
```

Existe algo equivalente ao operador de encadeamento opcional do JavaScript no PHP? Se não, me indiquem formas, métodos, recusos para simplificar o exemplo de código acima. Links de outras respostas são aceitas.

<sub>**OBS1:** A versão do PHP que ele usava era o `7.2`.</sub>

<sub>**OBS2:** Não conheço nada de PHP e nem achei nada relacionado aqui no SOpt. Pode servir também para ajudar os outros que possam ter a mesma duvida e curiosidade.</sub>

Comment: Você só quer saber se existe? É o que a pergunta me deu a entender. Nesse caso, acho que a [única resposta atual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/499062/69296) já responde; ou quer saber também como funciona e alguns detalhes importantes?

Comment: Sim, por favor. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, em PHP 8 podemos usar `session?->adminUser?->getAuthCredentials()?->email`

Referências:

- https://wiki.php.net/rfc/nullsafe_operator
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351737/is-there-a-nullsafe-operator-in-php

Comment: Putzs, só no PHP 8? Alguem vai ficar triste.